# Ionic 2 - Detect if screen is locked

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I searched for a long time now and could not find any result.

I need an Event or a Method in Ionic 2 to check the stat of the Phone Display - Is the display locked or unlocked.

Another option would be to check if the user is active. But think the Lockscreen would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Try with platform customization

```
constructor( private platform: Platform ) {
platform.ready().then(() => {    
    this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('[INFO] App paused');
    });

    this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('[INFO] App resumed');
    });
});
```

}

Comment: This works with one caveat; if you use the camera plugin, for instance, these are both triggered when it switches to the camera view.

Comment: Please try with add code into app.componet.ts and use  and if using camera view then you can handle it by  event  (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {}) call it when you try to access your camera or you can use listener more handling and pause or resume platform according to code Thank you c0r3yz